# Using Select Form in Drupal - How to display text value not ID value

Tags: forms, drupal, select, drupal-forms

How do I get the text in a Select dropdown list instead of the value in Drupal?

An example Select form:

```
$form = array();
  $form['test'] = array(
      '#title' => t("Choose something"),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => array(
        '1' => 'one',
        '2' => 'two',
        '3' => 'three',
      ),
  );
```

I am able to get the values but I only get the ID not the actual text.

I want to be able to print out "one" or "two" or "three", not their ids.

I'm trying to display it doing this:

```
drupal_set_message(t('You have selected %something.', array('%something' => ['values']['test'])));
```

Comment: could you not just key your options by text as well if you don't need the Id's?

Comment: I need the IDs to update/insert/delete from the database, but I want to display the text to assure the user of the action they chose.

Comment: you will need to load them then. Eg node_load or taxonomy_term_load